# Scraping a website where each login attempt generates a distinct, random, request url. (Python, Beautiful Soup)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use beautiful soup to scrape a website, which I must first login to. I attempted to do this in the same way shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cV21EOf5bbA.

The issue is that when logging in, each login request has a unique, procedural generated login request url, that expires after one use. So I can't just pass a url generated from a manual login attempt.

I tried following the instructions in the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cV21EOf5bbA), this time with my own site. Rather than successfully logging in, it directs the scraper back to the logi page, where it says the login request has expired.

What do I do in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say without being given the website or a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I find it helps when working with scrapers to think of yourself as a user, and then attempt to follow the common user paths.

Pretend you are a user of this website- how do you log in if the login page changes every time? As a user you probably start at a different page and then click a link to log in- you're not guessing a random url or typing anything into the bar, you're going to the home page and then following the login flow for that site.

Your scraper should do the same thing. Go to the home page and get the login page url, making sure to save relevant cookies in case that's part of the authentication scheme (it is very possible that your login attempt has "expired" because it's missing other data that would be in the cookie). Then on the page you're given from the home page insert your credentials.